# Como resolver o problema do quadrado quando arrastado pelo cursor do mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quando o movimento do mouse é rápido acaba saindo do quadrado e assim o quadrado não se mexe junto com o mouse, gostaria de saber uma solução para que o quadrado sempre acompanhe o mouse independente dele sair do campo do quadrado com o cursor o arrastando.

```css
#bloco{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: orangered;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="bloco"></div>

<script>

 bloco.style.top = 10+"px"
 bloco.style.left = 10+"px"

 bloco.onmousemove=function(e){
  
  
  x = e.movementX
  y = e.movementY
  
  if( e.buttons > 0 ){
   bloco.style.top = (parseInt(bloco.style.top)+y)+"px"
   bloco.style.left = (parseInt(bloco.style.left)+x)+"px"
  }
 }

 bloco.onmouseout=function(e){
  
  // k = 0;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Talvez seja melhor não vincular o mousemove ao bloco, e sim iniciar o movimento no clique, independente do "hover", acompanhando o mouse na pagina toda.

Comment: Acho que aqui tem algo parecido com o que vc quer, mas foi feito com jQuery... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/312832/algu%C3%A9m-poderia-me-dizer-como-consigo-fazer-esse-efeito-ao-passar-o-mouse/312864#312864

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie mais 2 eventos: `mousedown` e `mouseup`. Crie também uma variável que servirá como condição para que o bloco se mova.

O evento `mousemove` e `mouseup` você aplica ao documento todo. Assim, quando você clicar sobre o bloco (`mousedown`) irá mudar o estado da variável de *false* para *true*, fazendo com que o bloco se mova com o cursor do mouse. Ao soltar o botão (`mouseup`), a variável volta a ser *false*, fazendo com que o bloco não se mova mais.

**Veja:**

```js
var bloco = document.getElementById("bloco");

bloco.style.top = 10+"px"
bloco.style.left = 10+"px"

var drag;

bloco.onmousedown=function(e){
   drag = true;
}

document.onmouseup=function(e){
   drag = false;
}

document.onmousemove=function(e){
   
   x = e.movementX
   y = e.movementY


   if( e.buttons > 0 && drag ){
      bloco.style.top = (parseInt(bloco.style.top)+y)+"px"
      bloco.style.left = (parseInt(bloco.style.left)+x)+"px"
   }
   
}
```

```css
#bloco{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: orangered;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="bloco"></div>
```